# when i use my phpmyadmin it always tells me error but i don't know what's wrong with it

Tags: swift, phpmyadmin

when I test my database , it can read and write successfully but my phpmyadmin tells me something wrong in the mean while. But when I use it on my xcode post my url through Alamofire,the data is wrong.
like these:

Optional( { URL: http://XXXXXXX/register.php/?ema=123&pas=123 }{ Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "Upgrade, close"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        194
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 06 Mar 2019 09:26:15 GMT"
    );
    "Proxy-Connection" =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
    Upgrade =     (
        h2
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "PHP/5.4.45"
    );
} })
Optional(344 bytes)
FAILURE

And when I look through my phpmyadmin,it tells me there is something wrong:

```
{
    "pma_version": "4.4.15.10",
    "browser_name": "CHROME",
    "browser_version": "69.0.3497.100",
    "user_os": "Win",
    "server_software": "Apache",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
    "locale": "zh_CN",
    "configuration_storage": "disabled",
    "php_version": "5.4.45",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "Cannot read property '0' of null",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": 235,
                "func": "",
                "context": [
                    "                lastException = null;",
                    "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                    "            }",
                    "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                    "",
                    "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                    "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                    "    return report;"
                ],
                "column": "",
                "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "getFieldValidators",
                "line": 302,
                "column": "40",
                "context": [
                    " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                    " */",
                    "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                    "{",
                    "    // look for field bound validator",
                    "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                    "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                    "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    // look for registered validators"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "validate_field",
                "line": 418,
                "column": "21",
                "context": [
                    "{",
                    "    var args, result;",
                    "    var $field = $(field);",
                    "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                    "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                    "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                    "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                    "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                    "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                    "        } else {",
                    "            args = [];"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 511,
                "column": "13",
                "context": [
                    "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                    "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                    "        // run all field validators",
                    "        var errors = {};",
                    "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                    "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                    "        }",
                    "        // run all fieldset validators",
                    "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                    "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                    "        });"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
                "line": 279,
                "column": "33",
                "context": [
                    "     */",
                    "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                    "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                    "            var new_func = function () {",
                    "                try {",
                    "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                    "                } catch (x) {",
                    "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                    "                }",
                    "            };",
                    "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                ],
                "filename": "error_report.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.dispatch",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "8436",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
                "line": 374,
                "column": "19",
                "context": [
                    "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                    "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                    "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                    "\t\treturn;",
                    "\t}",
                    "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                    "};",
                    "",
                    "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                    "var touchHooks = ",
                    "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.r.handle",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "5139",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Object.trigger",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "7537",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "15404",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Function.each",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "2973",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
        "incomplete": "false",
        "partial": "true",
        "uri": "sql.php?target="
    },
    "script_name": "sql.php",
    "microhistory": {
        "current_index": "0"
    }
}
and the phpmyadmin's error:

{
    "pma_version": "4.4.15.10",
    "browser_name": "CHROME",
    "browser_version": "69.0.3497.100",
    "user_os": "Win",
    "server_software": "Apache",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
    "locale": "zh_CN",
    "configuration_storage": "disabled",
    "php_version": "5.4.45",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "Cannot read property '0' of null",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": 235,
                "func": "",
                "context": [
                    "                lastException = null;",
                    "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                    "            }",
                    "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                    "",
                    "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                    "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                    "    return report;"
                ],
                "column": "",
                "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "getFieldValidators",
                "line": 302,
                "column": "40",
                "context": [
                    " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                    " */",
                    "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                    "{",
                    "    // look for field bound validator",
                    "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                    "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                    "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    // look for registered validators"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "validate_field",
                "line": 418,
                "column": "21",
                "context": [
                    "{",
                    "    var args, result;",
                    "    var $field = $(field);",
                    "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                    "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                    "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                    "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                    "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                    "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                    "        } else {",
                    "            args = [];"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 511,
                "column": "13",
                "context": [
                    "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                    "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                    "        // run all field validators",
                    "        var errors = {};",
                    "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                    "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                    "        }",
                    "        // run all fieldset validators",
                    "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                    "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                    "        });"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
                "line": 279,
                "column": "33",
                "context": [
                    "     */",
                    "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                    "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                    "            var new_func = function () {",
                    "                try {",
                    "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                    "                } catch (x) {",
                    "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                    "                }",
                    "            };",
                    "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                ],
                "filename": "error_report.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.dispatch",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "8436",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
                "line": 374,
                "column": "19",
                "context": [
                    "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                    "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                    "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                    "\t\treturn;",
                    "\t}",
                    "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                    "};",
                    "",
                    "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                    "var touchHooks = ",
                    "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.r.handle",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "5139",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Object.trigger",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "7537",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "15404",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Function.each",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "2973",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
        "incomplete": "false",
        "partial": "true",
        "uri": "sql.php?target="
    },
    "script_name": "sql.php",
    "microhistory": {
        "current_index": "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clear up your question by only including the relevant part of the error and explain what you mean by with "on my xcode", do you mean in your swift code and is the issue with your code or phpadmin or both? Please try to modify your question so it's understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I have revised it again.

Comment: And what are you trying to do in phpAdmin when you get the error? What is the db command you are trying to execute?

Comment: I just try to write my data in it ,when I test it on postman ,it can write in my database successfully , though phpmyadmin tells me something wrong . but when I test it by swift   
 Alamofire.request("http://XXXXXXXXXX/register.php/?ema=\(name0)&pas=\(password)").responseJSON { response in...     the data it shows is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question. My api in my server is php,and there has some **warnings** in my php,I didn't slove it before,but few days ago it went wrong.But my other database running fluently.Then I try to slove these warnings,and it works.